# Passing an object key to a function

Tags: javascript, function, object, parameters

There's a lot I don't quite understand about javascript, so I may be misunderstanding something basic about objects. I understand there is a difference between . and [], so that's presumably part of the problem, but I don't know how to resolve this.

```
var game = {
    playerlvl:1
}

function displayinfo(name){
    var info = document.getElementById( name );
    info.innerHTML = game[name];
}

displayinfo(playerlvl);
```

I want the function to result in the same as:

```
document.getElementById("playerlvl").innerHTML = game.playerlvl;
```

Answer (score 2):

All you're missing in quotes:

```
displayinfo("playerlvl");
```

In JavaScript, you can access properties using dot notation and a *literal* property name (`game.playerlvl`), or using brackets notation and a *string* property name (`game["playerlvl"]`). (In ES6, brackets notation will also support `Symbol`s.) The string (or `Symbol`) in the brackets can be the result of any expression, including a variable/argument lookup. So `game[name]` works, if `name`'s value is a string or can reasonably be turned into one.

You're already correctly using brackets notation in `displayinfo`, you just need to pass it a string rather than using a literal. Your code using a literal is trying to use a variable called `playerlvl` on the `displayinfo(playerlvl)` line, which doesn't exist, and so gets a `ReferenceError`.

Answer (score 1):

Here i solved for you http://jsfiddle.net/xt7utnhz/

You was just missing `displayinfo("playerlvl");`